# How to get thumb value range of ScrollBar in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

For instance say we have a scrollbar for showing/manipulating data on some application. Scrollbar has min, max values and visible amount as well. But there is a bit confusing thing about the range of the values to be shown according scrollbar value.

As an example here is an image

[image]

and

[image]

But it is calculated according different sides of the thumb of the scrollbar.

Say I need to show some data from database, and min value will be min id and max value will be max id as well. and consider I want to show 100 items, and I am going to set visible amount to 100 in scrollbar. While scrolling If the value of scroolbar is equal to 1, and getting the range from the database will be as simple as just adding 100 (visible amount) to 1, but this won't work when the value is equal to max. So that is why I need to get value range of the scrollbar thumb, but when looking at scrollbar source code I could not find the implementation of this feature.

How to get min and max values of the thumb or visible value range of the scrollbar?

[image]

Comment: visibleAmount is the length of the thumb, the value of the scrollbar probably the middle of the thumb, so you can calculate start/end position

Comment: if the value is the middle of the thumb, then when the value is 1, start position of the thumb will be less than zero.

Comment: I meant how to get visible value range of the scrollbar.

Comment: oops ... good catch, just looked at the sources of ScrollBarSkin, which maps the thumb width to visibleAmount. Then you need to do additional math as long as the value < amount/2 (or > width - amount/2)

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollBar` indicates a position, not a range. The position is available via the `value` property. The `visualAmount` property determines the size of the slider.

If `value == max` the thumb is in the rightmost/bottommost position. Your "max value of thumb" would exceed `max`.

You should therefore decide how many items to display and calculate `visibleAmount` and `max` based on this:

```
max           = itemCount - displayedItems
visibleAmount = max * displayedItems / itemCount
```

Example for a `ScrollPane`-like implementation:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    StackPane.setAlignment(scrollBar, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

    VBox container = new VBox();
    StackPane.setAlignment(container, Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    StackPane root = new StackPane(container, scrollBar);

    InvalidationListener listener = o -> {
        // adjust scrollbar properties on resize of root or content
        double rootHeight = root.getHeight();
        double contentHeight = container.getHeight();

        double max = Math.max(0, contentHeight - rootHeight);
        scrollBar.setMax(max);
        scrollBar.setVisibleAmount(max * rootHeight / contentHeight);
    };
    root.heightProperty().addListener(listener);
    container.heightProperty().addListener(listener);

    // move container up based on the scrollbar value
    container.translateYProperty().bind(scrollBar.valueProperty().negate());

    // generate some content
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, (i & 1) == 0 ? Color.BLACK : Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        container.getChildren().add(rect);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: If visible amount is 200, and min value is 1, max is 10000.  When scrollbar value is 1, then visible values are from 1 to 200, and when the value is 10000 (max), then visible values are from 9800 to 10000. How to achieve this? You may use Label instead of HBox with rectangles.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple. Let the height of scrollbar be 600 and height of thumb is 200. Now if you substract the thumb's height and calculate the value to scroll according to leftover height(400) then there is no need of repressing the max value from the end.

You need to use some condition so that the thumb may not exceed the size. As here the thumb(200px) should not exceed 400px height as then it will not be visible to user.

Comment: please use real English words (vs. _u_ or similar)